# Make MySQL automatically refresh

Tags: java, mysql

I am inserting record in database(MySQL) based on user input. Immediate the data is inserted i want to retrieve the record i just inserted and display it in textfield.

But to my surprise nothing is retrieved. Is there some kind of way that will refresh my database immediately i insert data in db. I am using java!

```
public class Member {
    public Member(){
        final String nameMember = inputName.getText();

    //Button listener action
    newAccount.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
        {
            try {
                //this method insert data into db
                subscribe();
                //this retrieves the data inserted by subscribe()
                createdAccountDetails(nameMember);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Member.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });

    }



}
```

Comment: Did you commit? Can you confirm it exists in the db manually?

Comment: yes, the record was inserted.

Comment: Can we see more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to commit the data into db then only you can fetch it into results. But, it would be a bad practice to use insert and select as two different calls.
Either you can save the values in session and show them(if no exception occurred during insertion) or you can use a pl/sql function or procedure for the same.